# Reading text file from Windows and writing on a Linux Server in C

Tags: c#, c, linux

I am working on a Client-Server Application. the Client project is designed in VS 2012 C#, and the Server Side Coding is done in C. the basic aim is the Client app will read the file and will send it server and the Server app will write it on the Server. the text file which will be sent contains data

> ls.db

```
abs.tst=8745566

xyz.xys=2239482

kpy.llk=0987789
```

but when it is written on Server it written as

```
abs.tst=8745566xyz.xys=2239482kpy.llk=0987789
```

the application is perfectly reading the number of sent bytes. but there is some bytes missing at the end when the file is written. the Server size file has 6bytes missing when i checked the properties of Client file and server file I have given my client and Server code below kindly guide me how can i solve this issue

> Client Code in C#

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("local.db");
var binWriter = new   System.IO.BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.OpenWrite("l2.db"));
foreach (string line1 in lines)
{
    sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line1.ToString()));     
}
sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("EOF"));
```

> Linux based Server Code in C

```
FILE * file = fopen("local2.db","w+");
memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));
if(file!=NULL){
    num = SSL_read(ssl,buff,sizeof(buff));
    while(num>0){
        if(strcmp(buff,"EOF")==0){
            fclose(file);
            break;
        }else{
            fwrite(buff,1,num,file);
            memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));
            num = SSL_read(ssl,buff,sizeof(buff));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be a "\r\n" vs. "\n" issue. Under Windows lines in textfiles are terminated by "\r\n" whereas under Linux and other Unix flavors they are terminated by "\n".

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanx for the reply but even if i concat \n the md5 of both file recieve is not same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sslStream.write()` does not insert any line break (`\n` or `\r\n`) characters. `File.ReadAllLines()` [does not include line-end characters either](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So you are writing one long sequence of bytes without any separating line terminators. This should be easy enough to fix:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("local.db");
var binWriter = new   System.IO.BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.OpenWrite("l2.db"));
foreach (string line1 in lines)
{
    // Write line with UNIX-style end-of-line character
    sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line1.ToString() + "\n"));
}
sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("EOF"));
```

If you want to get an exact copy of the file, don't use `ReadAllLines()`. Use `ReadAllBytes()`:

```
byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("local.db");
sslStream.Write(filedata);
```

Comment: thanx for your kind response, but even if i concat the \n with the line1 still it is recieving 3 lesser bytes than the original files

Comment: Updated my answer. Note that the trick with ``"EOF"`` is problematic, since it will fail if your DB ever contains the string ``EOF``! It would be much better to just close the SSL connection or to send the length of the data first.